# Could anyone help me to plot the following function?

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction, graphics3d

Unfortunately Mathematica is not able to run the following program

area[d_]:=Pi*d^2/4

Q=80/1000

v[d_]:=Q/area[d]

[Nu]=10^-6

Reynolds[d_]:=v[d]*d/[Nu]

[Epsilon]=0.04/1000

CW[[Lambda]*,d*]:=1/Sqrt[[Lambda]]+2*Log[2.51/(Reynolds[d]*Sqrt[[Lambda]])+[Epsilon]/(3.71*d)]

Plot3D[CW,{[Lambda],0.0001,1},{d,0.15,0.5}]

To follow an immage of Mathematica's notebook.

[image]

So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Yes, sure: give me 1 minute.

Comment: What are paremeters in [Reynolds number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number)?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I changed the image: so what can you say now?

Comment: @user64494 Read in the image: now it is readble.

Comment: Did you try `CW[\[Lambda],D]` instead of `CW` in your `Plot3D` command?

Comment: @HigPerformance Okay, anyway now I enlarge the image: is still it unreadable?

Comment: @user64494 No, I did not try: give me some seconds.

Comment: @user64494 I tried but it is impossible to write \[Lambda] because Mathematica replace it with $\lambda$.

Comment: Also replace `D` by`d`: the former is reserved in Wolfram Laguage.

Comment: @user64494 Okay, I try: give me any seconds.

Comment: @user64494 I tried: there's nothing different.

Comment: Please post your Mathematica code instead of picture or LaTeX code.

Comment: @cvgmt I will edit the question: give me some minutes.

Comment: a pictorial [attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqQs4.png)

Comment: @cvgmt Question edited: so what can you say now?

Comment: @Syed Okay, so where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
area[d_] := Pi*d^2/4

Q = 80/1000

v[d_] := Q/area[d]

\[Nu] = 10^-6

Reynolds[d_] := v[d]*d/\[Nu]
\[Epsilon] = 0.04/1000

CW[\[Lambda]_, d_] := 1/Sqrt[\[Lambda]] + 
2*Log[2.51/(Reynolds[d] Sqrt[\[Lambda]]) + \[Epsilon]/(3.71 d)]

Plot3D[CW[\[Lambda], d], {\[Lambda], 0.0001, 1}, {d, 0.15, 0.5}]
```

Comment: Okay, perfect: question upvoted and approved. Anyway have you some advice for the future?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro. Check our website more often: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com